# Show different output depending on if value is greater than, less than, or equal to zero

Tags: php, integer, conditional-statements, comparison, font-awesome

I am fetching an integer value from my database which might be positive, negative, or zero.

I want to show an icon depending on the values relation to zero using FontAwesome's font icons.

- If the result `> 0`, I want to show the result with `icon-caret-up`.
- If the result `= 0`, I want to show the result with `icon-caret-right`.
- If the result `< 0`, I want to show the result with `icon-caret-down`.

So I added the following php code :

```
$reponse=mysql_query("My SQL Query");

if ($reponse > 0) {
    echo "<h1 class=\"uk-text-center uk-margin-bottom-remove\">".(mysql_result($reponse, 0))."<i class=\"uk-icon-caret-up\"></i></h1>";
}
elseif ($reponse == 0) {
    echo "<h1 class=\"uk-text-center uk-margin-bottom-remove\">".(mysql_result($reponse, 0))."<i class=\"uk-icon-caret-up\"></i></h1>";
}
else {
    echo "<h1 class=\"uk-text-center uk-margin-bottom-remove\">".(mysql_result($reponse, 0))."<i class=\"uk-icon-caret-down\"></i></h1>";
}
```

Whatever the result, even when it's a negative figure or equal to zero, I got only the first choice displaying the `icon-caret-up`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the mysql_* functions are deprecated, you need to use PDO or MySQLi for new development.

Secondly, as the documentation says, `mysql_query` returns a resource. http://php.net/mysql_query There are lots of examples on that page of how to use it.

You must fetch a row once you have executed the query. (Edit: I see you already know this because you're doing it in the next line, with `mysql_result` - you just need to use it before trying to do your comparison.)

`$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($reponse)` and then `$row` will be an array of values. Since you haven't shown the actual field names you're selecing I can't tell you what to do next, but read the docs.

Now, once you get that code set, you can simplify your printing of the HTML a lot.

```
$amount = mysql_result($reponse, 0);

if($amount > 0){
    $caret = 'up';
}else if($amount == 0){
   $caret = 'right';
}else{
   $caret = 'down';
}
echo '<h1 class="uk-text-center uk-margin-bottom-remove">'.$amount.'<i class="uk-icon-caret-'.$caret.'"></i></h1>';
```

Last line can also be `echo "<h1 class=\"uk-text-center uk-margin-bottom-remove\">{$amount}<i class=\"uk-icon-caret-{$caret}\"></i></h1>";` But I personally find escaping quotes annoying. So I switched it.

Comment: It work like a charm. Btw, many thanks for your advices, I'm a newbie in php, so I'm learning basic concepts, even if it's deprecated. It's just the first step before switching to PDO, and a php framework. Once again, many thanks for all. Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a condition block, perhaps establish a lookup array for your three-way comparison.  The spaceship operator can only return -1, 0, or 1, so your lookup just needs to translate those integers into words.

To avoid messy concatenation/interpolation, you can use placeholders in a template string and call upon `printf()` to display your content.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/49NQj))

```
$lookup = [
    -1 => 'down',
    0 => 'right',
    1 => 'up',
];

foreach ([13, 0, -5] as $amount) {
    printf(
        '<h1 class="uk-text-center uk-margin-bottom-remove">
            %s
            <i class="uk-icon-caret-%s"></i>
         </h1>',
        $amount,
        $lookup[$amount <=> 0]
    );
    echo "\n---\n";
}
```

Output:

```
<h1 class="uk-text-center uk-margin-bottom-remove">13<i class="uk-icon-caret-up"></i></h1>
---
<h1 class="uk-text-center uk-margin-bottom-remove">0<i class="uk-icon-caret-right"></i></h1>
---
<h1 class="uk-text-center uk-margin-bottom-remove">-5<i class="uk-icon-caret-down"></i></h1>
---
```

Since the spaceship operator is limited to 3 different return values, your lookup will need to maintain its current size (no room for contraction/expansion).  This means that you can, if to your taste, directly write the lookup payload into the third parameter of `printf()` without declaring `$lookup` ... I realize some devs will consider this less attractive/readable.

```
printf(
    '<h1 class="uk-text-center uk-margin-bottom-remove">
         %s
         <i class="uk-icon-caret-%s"></i>
     </h1>',
    $amount,
    [-1 => 'down', 0 => 'right', 1 => 'up'][$amount <=> 0]
);
```

In PHP8, you may find `match()` to a worthwhile technique -- it will keep your code concise and allow you to easily modify your translations beyond exactly 3 words.